# Can I use horizontal ScrollView with different UIview classes instead of UINavigationController to navigate to different viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview

I am thinking of creating `UIView` classes and adding all views to single horizontal `UIScrollView` so that when we are done with one view and click next button, it slides to next view instead of creating multiple `UIViewControllers` and use `UINavigationController` to navigate to next page. .
Is it a good idea or causes performance issue? Can you please tell me which way is better and why?

Comment: It is definitely possible to do that but, if you want to simulate a navigation controller, why not make one?

Comment: ohr: I can use navigation controller but I want to try scroll view. But I am kind of afraid to use scrollview because I think scroll view loads all views and holds in its content view. so all objects for view have been created and loaded event though we just work with one view at a time. But in UINavigation Controller, all objects will be released except the object of the view controller which is being displayed. Is this true?

Comment: You can create View controller for every view that you want to put in scrollView, and then  call viewInScrollView = myViewController.view . The ViewControllers view will start load only if you directly call property myViewController.view, just put it in your scroll view at the moment when you slide to the next page

Comment: does this solution solved your problem?

Comment: user1090590: thanks for your comment. So If I create UIViewController files, I need to create xib files, right? My plan is having just one ViewController and xib file with scroll view in it. Then load UIViews in scroll view. If I wanted to create UIViewControllers, I would have used UINavigationController. The following questions disturbing me. 1. does having more number of viewcontrollers and xib files affect application performance? 2. Adding UIVIew classes to scroll view loads all objects and eats more memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off going with the navigation controller in terms of memory management. At least doing so will make that part of the process easier, but there's no reason why you can't do this with a scroll view, you just have to keep track of what elements are on and off screen so you can alloc/dealloc different objects at the right time.

However, if you do decide to go the scroll view route you can simple make buttons on your scroll view that adjust the scroll view's content offset.x property to jump around between pages, and you can use this to set up the scroll view:

Simply add the number of pages you want as entries in the array below, and the scroll view will be dynamically adjusted to accommodate new views for every page.

```
[myScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First View",@"Second  View",@"Third View",@"Fourth View",@"Fifth View", nil];//number of views you want in your scroll view

[arrayOfViews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx,BOOL *stop) {
    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 * idx, 0, 320, 480)];
    float randNum = arc4random() % 255;
    [subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:randNum/255 green:randNum/255 blue:randNum/255 alpha:1.0]];
    [myScrollView addSubview:subView];
    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * (idx + 1), 480)];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding all your `UIView`s to a `UIScrollView` will indeed load everything to memory (there will be no automatic release of unnecessary stuff) so you'd need to release these views yourself. Hope this gives you an idea;

Load your first view on a scrollView with 1) a button to create (and add) the next view and scroll to it 2) Your new view needs a back button which will move the scroll to your first view and nil your second view.

```
1)-(void) moveToSecondView{
   //iVar of your second view
   secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320,0,320,480)];
   //Previously created button with a returnToFirstView selector
   [secondView addSubview:backButton];
   [scrollView addSubview:secondView];
   [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:secondView.frame animated:YES];
}

2)-(void) returnToFirstView{
    [secondView removeFromSuperview];
    secondView = nil;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:firstView.frame animated:YES];
  }
```

Comment: Both are desired answers that I am looking for. But I can only select one.